# How do you get specific tags from the_content?

Tags: filters, the-content

How would I grab specific tags from the_content? For example, I'd like to pull a list of all h1 tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) you can create [a regex pattern](https://github.com/zeeshanu/learn-regex) to find and extract tags (and their content).

With Wordpress's `post_content` hook, you can find and list all the H1's within current posts content with something like:

```
add_action('the_content', function ($content){

    // look for <h1> tags and text therein, anticipate class/id name
    $findH1s = preg_match_all('/<h1 ?.*>(.*)<\/h1>/i', $content, $h1s);

    // if found, show above content
    if (is_array($h1s) && isset($h1s[0]))   
        return "<pre>H1's in this post: ".print_r(￼ $h1s[0] ,true)."</pre>".$content;

    // if none found, just return content as-is
    return $content;
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I need to spend more time figuring out how to write regex patterns, as it has always been a deficiency of mine. Thanks so much, David.

Comment: no problem. learning regex is worth every minute put into it. tools like www.phpliveregex.com and regex101.com are great when learning as well.